# Broadcom LY-PHY WLAN card does not work in 14.04.1 on HP Mini 210

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I have an HP Mini 210-1040NR that previously ran Windows 7 Starter. Because of extreme lag I downloaded and installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 and installed from a USB drive made by pendrivelinux. First, I used the demo and installed the driver that came from some source file. It ran nicely and I successfully connected to the internet. I installed Ubuntu, but then the wifi driver vanished. I edited my settings in Software and Updates to match that of the Live Demo's, and the driver appeared. However, when I attempted to install it, I got about 10% through, then it stopped and I eventually had to cancel it.

My Wireless driver is, according to feedback from the

```
$ lspci -nn -d 14e4
Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
```

It would be really helpful if the driver or whatever I need to fix this was downloadable from any OS, because I don't have any access to ethernet. If it's the only way though, I might be able to find a way.

Comment: Here you go: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#STA_-_No_Internet_access. All you need to do is ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I installed my original Windows 7 OS on the laptop and created new Ubuntu install media, downloaded from another mirror on the Ubuntu site. Installed it, and boom. Wifi suddenly works. Thanks for trying to help, though!

Answer (score 0):

This normally works `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-dkms` and `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer` and reboot
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7exlzch25ap6uha/b43.zip?dl=0

And copy the files to /lib/firmware/b43

Comment: You should read the question, especially the last paragraph.

Comment: I used a Mac to download the file, then moved it to a USB, which I plugged in to my Ubuntu machine. Apparently, even though I am the original Administrator of the machine, I don't have sufficient privileges to make edits to the /lib directory.

Comment: Try `sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43`

Comment: Using information I collected from elsewhere, I went into root mode and used 'cp -r' to copy the extracted folder of b43 to the '/lib/firmware/b43' directory. Either I put a folder in a folder, or the install command still didn't work.